# Main wallet unspent transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoind, listunspent, importaddress

I have a question about an unspent transaction, we know that after some transactions we have a change address created by the main address, now imagine that Bob mined 6 BTC, now he transferred 2 of the two Alice and now in Bob's change address there is 4 BTC and they are unspent, now the question is that if I try to get unspent transaction of the main wallet with bitcoin core that I imported the address of Bob's main wallet, will it show me 4 BTC? or it can show if I try to get with child address?

Another question is that, is there any way to find a parent or main wallet, child keies?

Answer (score 0):

All wallets will calculate and show the same amount as the "balance" for an address. In your example, all wallets would show the balance as 4 BTC. There are exceptions if a wallet is faulty or is not synchronised (not up-to-date, doesn't yet know about latest transactions).

If you import an address into a wallet, it will show the correct balance but it will show that amount as "watch-only" or "non-spendable".

There is no way to discover private-keys from addresses.